# limit carriage return in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the number of carriage return in a string like so

```
var str = str.split(/\n/).length;
```

I would like to limit my string so that after 5 `cr`'s the string removes only those carriage returns after the max allowed.
Can anyone lend a hand on the syntax for this.
Thank you, heres my attempt.

this flattens the **entire** string after 5,  I would like to **retain the first 5** then flatten then string

```
function countLineBreaks(str){
    var n = str.split(/\n/).length;
        return n;
};
var n = countLineBreaks(myStr);

if(n > 5)
    str = str.replace(/\n/g, " ");// replace cr's with empty space after 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the array, merge all items after 5, and then join it back in.

```
function trimString(str) {
  var lines = str.split(/\n/);
  if(lines.length > 5) {
    var rest = lines.slice(5);
    lines.length = 5;
    lines[5] = rest.join(' ');
  }
  return lines.join('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it with regexes, but you can also just do it with splitting and joining:

```
var split = str.split("\n");
var first6 = split.splice(0, 6); // remove first 6 elements into first6
var result = first6.join("\n") + (split.length ? " " + split.join(" ") : "");
```